# Desorganização nos nomes e tags desnecessárias relacionadas ao HTTP

Tags: debate, suporte, tags

Tenho algumas dúvidas/sugestões quanto algumas tags relacionadas ao http...

A tag [response](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/response) é para respostas HTTP assim como [http-request](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-request) é para requisições? Se sim não deveriam ambas ou nenhuma serem prefixadas com "http-"?

Se existe a tag [http-headers](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-headers) não deveria existir uma `http-body`? Existe uma tag [body](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/body) porém parece que ela é usada para o elemento HTML `<body>` (não possui uma wiki dizendo pra que deveria ser usada)

É realmente necessário haver múltiplas tags para métodos ([get](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/get), [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post) e [http-post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-post) que parecem estar duplicadas) e status ([404](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/404) e [http-status-code-403](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-403)) *****? Usar as tags [http-métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-m%c3%a9todos) e [http-status](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status) já não é o suficiente? Estranhamente, essas duas tags já estão em português (apesar que essa segunda pode ter sido sem querer)

Como estamos no StackOverflow **em Português** não faria mais sentido usar as palavras em português e talvez adicionar um sinônimo em inglês?

***** Pode haver outras

Answer (score 5):

De forma geral posso concordar com a primeira avaliação, mas alguma coisa me diz que `response` está sendo usado em contextos que não são de HTTP, então precisa arrumar tudo para fazer uma mudança e dissociar cada contexto. Estou enganado?

Duvido que tenha muita utilidade e que vá ser usada uma *tag* `http-body`.

Os métodos de acesso me parecem estar duplicados mesmo, mas pode ser que tenha contexto diferente, teria que avaliar tudo para poder mexer e tornar sinônimo.

Para os códigos de erro acho que é fácil padronizar e criar sinônimo, duvido que tenha algo diferente usando essas *tags*. E acho que elas são úteis para alguns casos. Alguém vê diferente?

Esses termos são bem técnicos em inglês não acho que deveria ser em português.

Comment: Quanto a `response` também acho que uma ou outra não é relacionada ao HTTP, mas poucas. Algumas que poderiam ter uma tag `http-body`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/361465, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/301436, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/225892, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/338010 entre outras. Talvez então criar tags para os ranges (1xx, 2xx, 3xx, etc)? Mas acho que seria demais também se for manter os status, sugiro um parão `http-status-xxx`. Sobre a tradução, então `http-métodos` deveria ser alterada para `http-méthod`, não?